# Any way to tell whether a javascript function has returned or not?

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value, undefined

I'm currently writing some code that wrappers user-written JavaScript functions, and have come across a point in the logic where I would like to trigger a particular behaviour if the function in question never returns a value i.e. the `return` keyword is never evaluated.

Currently I am assuming that if a function returns `undefined`, it has not returned, however this is not strictly true—due to the fact a function can always `return undefined`, or return the value of an undefined property.

With a function call you can always tell how many parameters were used due to the `arguments.length` property, I was wondering if anyone knew of a similar trick for a function's return value?

So, is it possible to tell the difference between the return values of `a`, `b` or even `c`

```
var a = function(){  };
var b = function(){ return undefined; };
var c = function(){ if(1){}else{return undefined;}; };
```

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Comment: I'm curious: What's the use case? Why do you care which of a, b, or c occurred? They are functionally identical. A difference that makes no difference *is* no difference... :-)

Comment: Don't forget `return;` and `return void <expr>` which also give `undefined`.

Comment: If you have access to source before it gets interpreted, you could replace the final `}` with `return someConst;` where `someConst` is something very unlikely to be returned by the user, then return `undefined` from your wrapper.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's really rather a singular use-case, it's part of a game where coding will be involved - and different things will occur depending on the code used. I was just testing out a few ideas and had not come across this issue before. The responses are sadly as I expected though.. rather a subtle annoyance from JS's pov. Ah well c'est la vie :) Looks like I'll have to try a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot reliably, cross-browser, tell whether a function returned by just reaching the end of its code, using `return` without a value, or using `return undefined`. This is covered by [Section 13.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) of the specification.

Another answer here suggests you *could* do it by analyzing the source code of the function. However, there is no standard mechanism for doing that. Though nearly all browsers make some form of the source available from  `Function#toString`, some do not (mostly mobile browsers), and it is not defined by the specification. But if you have a certain set of browsers that you support, and they all have it, that would be your only real option — but even then, you wouldn't necessarily know which code branch was taken within the function.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving a function blank will also return undefined, so a, b and c will all return identical values.

The only way to achieve something like this would to actually set some kind of flag in the function itself, but I'm guessing you want to be able to do this independently of the implementations of the actual function.

Comment: +1 thanks. yep I started down this path but then started to realise just what would be involved, basically ended up with almost re-parsing the code involved :S

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell the difference.

If you really wanted to, you could try to analyze the function's source code and determine whether it has any return statements, and if not, then assume it won't return a value. Of course this would be a bit harder to determine if a function sometimes returns and others not (eg. a return statement in an if-block)

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, very true, but I really was hoping to avoid anything on this level though.. if only js had some form of relection ability or a way of defining the default return value.

Answer (score 2):

This is crazy and definitely not recommended, it creates a copy of the function, modifies the function body and uses `eval`

```
function returnProxy(func,args) {
    var returnFlag = Math.random()+"";

    // create new function based on passed function body
    var fullFuncBody = func.toString();
    var tmpFuncStr = "function  "+ fullFuncBody.substr(fullFuncBody.indexOf("("));

    tmpFuncStr = tmpFuncStr.substr(0,tmpFuncStr.length-1)+"\nreturn '"+returnFlag+"'}";

    var tmpFunc;
    eval("tmpFunc = "+tmpFuncStr); // really bad things

    var funcOut = tmpFunc.apply(this,args);

    return {
        out: (funcOut == returnFlag) ? undefined : funcOut,
        returned: (returnFlag != funcOut)
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a function like this,

```
function someFunction(action) {
    switch(action) {
        case 1:
            return undefined;
        case 2:
            return "hello";
    }
}
```

You would use the proxy function like this:

```
returnProxy(someFunction,[1]); // instead of calling someFunction(1)
```

With the first parameter being the function itself , and second parameter an array of parameters

The return value will be an object with 2 properties, `out` contains the function result, and `returned` is a boolean indicating if the function returned or not

Example output,

```
returnProxy(someFunction,[1]); // {out: undefined, returned: true}
returnProxy(someFunction,[2]); // {out: "hello", returned: true}
returnProxy(someFunction,[3]); // {out: undefined, returned: false}
```

Comment: I like this just for its insanity!

Answer (score 0):

You can only tell if you invoke the functions through a wrapper, but I'm not sure if this is suitable for your usecase.

```
function invoker(f) {
    var actualFunc = f,
        invokeCount = 0;

    function invoke() {
        invokeCount = invokeCount +1;
        return actualFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    function invoked() {
       return invokeCount;
    }

    return {
      invoke: invoke,
      invoked: invoked
    };
}

var a = function(){  };
var b = function(){ return undefined; };
var c = function(){ if(1){}else{return undefined;}; };

var ainvoker = new invoker(a);    

alert(ainvoker.invoke());
alert(ainvoker.invoked());
```

Comment: Please can you explain how ainvoker.called() would return a different value from binvoker.called()? I also considered this approach but I don't think it actually solves the issue.

Comment: It counts the number of times it is invoked. I assume it still holds that javascript is not multithreaded, so if call() is done, it has increased invoked with 1 AND returned from a() (or b()). The difference would be that for ainvoker.called() === 1 and for binvokver.called() === 0. But I might be missing something....

Comment: @rene Suggesting `return actualFunc();` to `return actualFunc.apply(this, arguments);` and maybe you chose to name it `call` on purpose but this seems like you may have forgotten `invokerinstance.call` should mean something different.